# Using Countif when searching for partial strings in cells

Tags: vba, excel

Looking for some help using both COUNTIF and INSTR to determine the number of separate occurrences of a string in a set of data. I have the COUNTIF statements working for the cell values, but I am now trying to dig into the cells, and identify how many instances of a particular string occur across the entire column.

The code I have is as follows:

```
j = 2

Cells(2, 11) = "Active, non-corresp add"
Cells(3, 11) = "No start date of res"
Cells(4, 11) = "Invalid address"
Cells(5, 11) = "Active ID, no country"
Cells(6, 11) = "Invalid address format"
Cells(7, 11) = "Invalid characters in address"

While Cells(j, 11) <> vbNullString
    s = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("Addresses Master").Range("N:N"), Cells(j, 11))

    If s <> 0 Then
        Cells(j, 12) = s
    End If

    t = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Worksheets("Addresses Master").Range("N:N"), Cells(j, 11), Worksheets("Addresses Master").Range("I:I"), 1)

    If t <> 0 Then
        Cells(j, 13) = t
    End If

    u = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Worksheets("Addresses Master").Range("N:N"), Cells(j, 11), Worksheets("Addresses Master").Range("I:I"), 0)

    If u <> 0 Then
        Cells(j, 14) = u
    End If

    k = 15

    If Cells(j, 11) = "Review address" Then
        p = 0
    Else
        p = 1
    End If

    While k <= 19
        v = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Worksheets("Addresses Master").Range("N:N"), Cells(j, 1), Worksheets("Addresses Master").Range("I:I"), p, Worksheets("Addresses Master").Range("C:C"), Cells(1, k))
        If v <> 0 Then
            Cells(j, k) = v
            v = 0
        End If
        k = k + 1
    Wend

    j = j + 1
    s = 0
    t = 0
    u = 0
Wend
```

In the cells being searched, there could be a combination of the 6 strings that I am looking for (Cells 2 - 7).

Edit: clarified title

Comment: Are you trying to count the instances of the phrase in a sentence?  like "cat sat" within "cat sat on mat" and "my cat sat there" ?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav: Exactly

Comment: May not suit, but why don't you have the formula's added once and filled down?  Also, the solution, could also be an array formula, like `=SUM(--NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("nath",E1:E10000))))` for example looking for `nath` in the range `E1:E10000` or using wildcards as your answer suggests

Comment: What error do you have for this code? also I don't understand what is the purpose of  "p", because you count in both versions, 0 or 1. I think you can get rid of this "p" from that formula.

Comment: @BOB: No error. Just looking for a way to do it. As for the "p", it is used to denote certain constraints in an older version, but is superfluous here.

Comment: You need to specify and example of what you want, in your question because I don't understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue through the use of wildcards.

Instead of trying to use something like InStr, the use of an asterisk before and after the cell location being searched for allows for the Countif function to search inside the cell.

i.e. `"*" & cells(j,11) & "*"`

The code then becomes:

```
j = 2

Cells(2, 11) = "Active, non-corresp add"
Cells(3, 11) = "No start date of res"
Cells(4, 11) = "Invalid address"
Cells(5, 11) = "Active ID, no country"
Cells(6, 11) = "Invalid address format"
Cells(7, 11) = "Invalid characters in address"

While Cells(j, 11) <> vbNullString
    s = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets("Addresses Master").Range("N:N"), "*" & Cells(j, 11) & "*")

    If s <> 0 Then
        Cells(j, 12) = s
    End If

    k = 13

    p = 1

    While k <= 19
        v = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Worksheets("Addresses Master").Range("N:N"), "*" & Cells(j, 11) & "*", Worksheets("Addresses Master").Range("I:I"), p, Worksheets("Addresses Master").Range("C:C"), Cells(1, k))
        If v <> 0 Then
            Cells(j, k) = v
            v = 0
        End If
        k = k + 1
    Wend

    j = j + 1
    s = 0
    t = 0
    u = 0
Wend
```

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out. I might recommend more descriptive names than `j` and `p` and `s`. In a year, or even a month when you look at this code again, these "painfully obvious" variables and their purpose will be totally foreign to you and it will take a while to figure out what they mean again. If you were to rename `j` to `resultColumn` (for example), it would be much more obvious, easier to read, and the numbers assigned to them would be much less magical and would take on more meaning.

Comment: I would agree. For the code that will be used on a semi-regular basis, I do use more descriptive names. This is a one-off code to review 150k breaks.